# Finding within parsed div [Simple HTML DOM]

Tags: php

I want to fetch the `<a>` link within the div glance_details. I can't really make it work. Don't worry about including and the url and things, that is all correct.

```
$redirect = $url;
$html3 = file_get_html($redirect);
foreach($html3->find('div.glance_details') as $element3) {
     $html3->find('a',0)->outertext;  
}
```

with

```
$redirect = $url;
$html3 = file_get_html($redirect);
foreach($html3->find('div.glance_details') as $element3) {
    $knaoss = $element3->plaintext;
    echo $knaoss;
}
```

I can fetch the plain text content of the div, but what I want is the anchor (a) that will be within the div.

This is similar to what I receive in $knaoss if I remove the ->plaintext:

```
<div class="glance_details">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">
        <img src="http://www.example.com/img.png">
    </a>
    "This is a description of the example"
</div>
```

Though all I want from it is:

```
http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: add $html3 content in the question

Comment: Could be 'jQuery' an option for you?

Comment: Do you mix up php and javascript (jQuery) here?

Comment: @saurabhkamble how do you mean?

Comment: what does $html3 variable contain

Comment: Don't know if I'm mixing something up, but I have had similar foreach loops work, just the $html3->find('a',0)->outertext; that is new really. Finding something within what I've fetched..

Comment: @saurabhkamble It contains the fetched website?

Comment: @Franco I'm sure jQuery could be, but it'd be nice to do it the same way I've done with other things I've fetched.. I've just never tried to find something within what I've fetched

Comment: Ok. can you explain what the zero in : '$html3->find('a',0)' should do?

Comment: @Franco I'm not sure to be honest. Something about which one if multiple a I should fetch?

Comment: Ok, I think you are wrong referencing the element you want to fetch. Can you post here the HTML you are trying to fetch?

Comment: @Franco See my edit and you might understand a little more

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple. Only had to change:

```
$redirect = $url;
$html3 = file_get_html($redirect);
foreach($html3->find('div.glance_details') as $element3) {
    $knaoss = $element3->plaintext;
}
```

to

```
$redirect = $url;
$html3 = file_get_html($redirect);
foreach($html3->find('div.glance_details > a') as $element3) {
    $knaoss = $element3->href;
}
```

to find the **href** within div.glance_details. Problem was I used words like "url" and "link" instead of href, and could therefor not make it work.